# HTML5 audio lagging when pausing an mp3 on Firefox and Safari Windows 7

Tags: firefox, windows-7, safari, mp3, html5-audio

When pausing an mp3 file which is played with HTML5 audio in Firefox and Safari on Windows 7, the playback is not stopped immediately, it continues to play for a while (on Firefox the lag is longer).
This pause delay does not appear in Chrome on Windows 7, neither in Firefox, Safari, Chrome on Mac.

Here's my HTML5 code:

```
<audio class="audio-player" type="audio/mpeg" style="display: none;"></audio>
```

JS load and play code:

```
$(".audio-player").attr("src", "file.mp3");
$(".audio-player").get(0).play();
```

JS pause code:

```
$(".audio-player").get(0).pause();
```

I have also tried showing and using the HTML5 audio player controls for play and pause in the browser, and the lag still appears.

Another thing I tried was to create an audio element in JS, without using HTML5 and it is still lagging when paused:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.setAttribute("src","file.mp3");
audio.play();
```

and later calling for pause:

```
audio.pause();
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What size is the audio file you use? Btw you can also do audio.src = 'file.mp3';

Comment: Finally found my copy of firefox portable and it works just fast here. Are you sure you have the latest version? I really don't know what is going wrong over there. I will write a little piece of code for you creating an ObjectURL to use.

Comment: Btw what happens if you add `controls` to your HTML5 element and play/pause it through the buttons? Does that work?

Comment: Do you also get that lag [here](http://jsbin.com/vicox/3)?